# Insertion of last element in Python

Tags: python, list

```py
# Code 1
t1 = ['CS', 'IP', 'IT']
t1.insert(len(t1)-1, t1.pop())
print(t1)     # output is ['CS', 'IP', 'IT']
```

```py
# Code 2
t1 = ['CS', 'IP', 'IT']
x = t1.pop()
t1.insert(len(t1)-1, x)
print(t1)    # output is ['CS', 'IT', 'IP']
```

The above two code snippets are similar, yet the output is different. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first scenario `len(t1)` is run before `t1.pop()` so when list still contains 3 elements. The result of `len(t1)-1` is 2 and `'IT'` lands up in third place of list.
In the second one `t1.pop()` is run and pops last element from the list so when `len(t1)` is run after it returns 2. The whole statement `len(t1)-1` returns 1.

Comment: @Sarv answer should be accepted if you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations.

The insert in #1 uses an index of 2 as the length is retrieved before the last element is popped, i.e. `IT` is being inserted at index 2 of the list `['CS', 'IP']`.

The insert in #2 inserts at index 1 as the last element of the list has already been popped, i.e. inserting `IT` at index 1 of the list `['CS', 'IP']`.